# How to add StackLayout to an activity

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and mobile developing, and I am having trouble loading a stacklayout to an activity. So I have this layout in a class:

```cs
public class TestStackLayout : ContentPage
{
    public TestStackLayout ()
    {
        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 0,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = 
            {
                new Label
                {
                    Text = "StackLayout"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And this activity, which is called in the mainactivity with a button:

```cs
[Activity (Label = "TestActivity")] 
public class TestActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I add my TestStackLayout to the TestActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TestStackLayout` is defined as a `ContentPage` and not a layout by itself. So it presents a page on your app (on every platform).

And you dont need to add an Activity for every page when you are working with Xamarin.Forms (thats the key). You just need a MainActivity which loads Xamarin.Forms and the Application. The rest is done by Xamarin.Forms.

Just look at [this sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Todo/) from Xamarin. You can [dive into the code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo/PCL) directly to understand whats happen.

To start with Xamarin.Forms read [this introduction guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/).